# Hide/unhide Rows Based on Content of a Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want my current script which give me a custom menu,sidebar and hides cell based on a value to also include unhide if the cell is changed away from the value.

### E.g.

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .createMenu('x Tools')
        .addItem('Instructions', 'showSidebar')
        .addItem('Change y Form', 'openform')
        .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .setTitle('Instructions')
        .setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .showSidebar(html);
}

function openform() {
    showURL("https://docs.google.com/a/xxx/viewform")
}

function showURL(href) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(50).setWidth(200);
    app.setTitle("Add Project to x");
    var link = app.createAnchor('Open x Form ', href).setId("link");
    app.add(link);
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    doc.show(app);
}

function onEdit(e) {
    Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);
    var cellEdited = e.range.getA1Notation();
    Logger.log('cellEdited: ' + cellEdited);
    if (cellEdited === "C12" && e.value === "X") {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        theSheet.hideRows(13, 4);
    };
}
```

My problem is I tried adding a 2nd if statement - didnt get error but just didnt unhide. Tried using else and got error. Basic Idea is if the cell c12 is X then rows 13,14,15,16 should be hidden, if it is anything else the cells should be visible. What I have now works for the hiding however it doesnt unhide the cells if you change the X to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just have to unhide in the same way, just changing the expression to !== "X", and using the [.showRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showRows(Integer,Integer)) method.

```
if (cellEdited === "C12" && e.value !== "X") {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    theSheet.showRows(13, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you just have to write the code to unhide the rows.

Try it in else block in this way:

```
else if (cellEdited === "C12" && e.value !== "X") {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    theSheet.showRows(13, 4);
     }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I still got an error while using the Else however once i removed the else the rest all worked. I think my biggest issue was not knowing that the command was Showrows. Any thanks alot it was a great help!